# Pysqlite setup error

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

When intalling pysqlite on my Mac I get permission denied when it tries to create pysqlite2-doc dir. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

What exact versions of Mac OSX and Python are you using?  All modern ones come with `sqlite` already there and available for Python.  Anyway, if you need to install something in a protected, you need [sudo](http://osxfaq.com/man/8/sudo.ws) -- check it out!